# Remove double quotes from json encoded string using php for dhtmlxscheduler

Tags: php, jquery, json, dhtmlx

I need some help with JSON and jquery.

I developing application with dhtmlx scheduler. I want to create dhtmlx sections dynamically.

I generating json_encoded string using php json_encode function given in following

```
["{key:23, label:'T23 (34)'}","{key:24, label:'T24 (34)'}","{key:26, label:'T26 (26)'}","{key:35, label:'T35 (25)'}"]
```

Ajax call function for this

```
$.ajax({
            url:"updatetablestr.php",
            type:"get",
            data:{id:id},
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend:function(){},
            success:function(q)
            {
            var JSONString = JSON.stringify(q);
            var output=JSONString.replace(/\"/g,"");                
            scheduler.updateCollection("MyList",output);
            }
            })
```

PHP function is,

```
$resarray=json_encode($array);
echo preg_replace('/"([a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9_]*)":/', '$1:', $resarray);
```

i removed first and last quotes using jquery

```
var JSONString = JSON.stringify(q);
var output =JSONString.replace(/\"/g,"");
```

after this jquery code i could get my output

```
[{key:23, label:'T23 (34)'}","{key:24, label:'T24 (34)'}","{key:26, label:'T26 (26)'}","{key:35, label:'T35 (25)'}]
```

This output is what i need. when i use static code like

```
 var output= [{key:23, label:'T23 (34)'}","{key:24, label:'T24 (34)'}","{key:26, label:'T26 (26)'}","{key:35, label:'T35 (25)'}]
```

is working . When i implement dynamically which generated php , JSON.stringify is not working..
that time its showing the following error

```
scheduler.updateCollection("MyList",output);
```

**"Uncaught TypeError: Function.prototype.apply: Arguments list has wrong type"** 
in dhtmlxschduler.js

While statically working with same string why it's not working when dynamically generated using php and jquery..

Comment: You could try fixing your input source...

Comment: Why would you `JSON.stringify` a string? Except if you `JSON.parse()`'d it to make q an object, this makes no sense to me.

Comment: Then your PHP is wrong. Please show your PHP code so we can fix that. Then your JavaScript will be infinitely simpler.

Comment: Could you provide both PHP and Ajax call (with success callback function) ?

Comment: @Arockiaraj Why do you remove first and last doublequotes? It is strange you have no error when doing `var output = [{key: 23, label:'T23 (34)'}","{...]` due to remaining doublequotes

Comment: @TouPye I need without double quotes. Otherwise i wont' get output in dhtmlx sections